# how to animate (scroll bottom to top like credits scenen) a really long image in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I have a long (long 3 pages long) image or table.

how can I scroll animate it as part of my powerpoint presentation.

I tried credits animation but it stop after 1 page. I tried as table. I tried as image.

any suggestions ?

Comment: the only option I see is to create a video - of me scrolling and adding that. sound tedious..

Comment: ok - I did not get any answer,  I make the excel the size of my video and did a video using sscreen capture while I scrolled.